# How can block overflow with high:auto in CSS?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I made my site layout by using [layzilla](http://www.layzilla.com/) like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/maBAxf?p=preview).

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="top_block header">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background right-sidebar">
    </div>
    <div class="right_block right-sidebar">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background middle-sidebar">
    </div>
    <div class="right_block middle-sidebar">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="top_block middle-sidebar-up">
                <div class="content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background left-sidebar">
    </div>
    <div class="right_block left-sidebar">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="bottom_block left-sidebar-down">
                <div class="content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background container">
    </div>
    <div class="center_block container">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works well except sidebar is too long.

And I use this with AngularJS and uiRouter like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/uTt3Di?p=preview).

It doesn't work when sidebar is too long, the layout is broken.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the css `max-height:100vh;` 
This sets the maximum height to 100% of the viewport heigth.

Like this:

```
<div class="background left-sidebar" style="max-height:100vh">
```

If that would be too much, you could use 99vh instead.

Also, have you thought about using Bootstrap to lay out your page?

Comment: My company does not use Bootstrap.:-( Using`style="max-height:100vh"` works block backgroud, but text is still overflowed....

Comment: I think i may got you wrong. Could you please specify your question a little bit more?

Comment: I want limit all content in Max height. If context is long, it has scrolled in each box. [In this case](https://plnkr.co/edit/maBAxf?p=preview)  text is overflowed.